# Requesting book for Hyperbolic manifold

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, hyperbolic-geometry

Can anyone suggest some basic book for Hyperbolic manifolds?

What is this area about?

Answer (score 1):

A hyperbolic manifold is (naturally enough) a manifold in which each region looks locally like a hyperbolic space.

Though not quite "basic," try John G. Ratcliff, ***Foundations of hyperbolic manifolds***, Graduate Texts in Mathematics, 149 (2nd ed.), Berlin, New York: Springer-Verlag  (2006)